# How to configure alert manager with helm

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I have installed Prometheus with the Helm Prometheus-stack. I am now trying to configure alertmanager to add a new receiver. But I fail to understand where to configure it.

Logs of alertmanager tells me it reads its config from its local disk. If I look to the read file, it gives an almost empty config.
If I try to edit the base value file with:

alertmanager.config.... then the config file is not changes.
Same if I try to create a alertmanagerconfigs.monitoring.coreos.com, the config value stays empty.

I am very confused at where I am supposed to put the config of alert manager, could any one lead me to it?
Thank you!